# Collapse TabPanel in Window

Tags: extjs, tabpanel, extjs2

I have an `Ext.Window` with border layout. This window contain a grid and a TabPanel. This is my TabPanel:

```
tabMsg = new Ext.TabPanel(
    id:'TabPanel',
    region : 'south',
    plain : true,
    collapsible: true,
    titleCollapse:'Modify?',
    collapsed: true,
    hideCollapseTool: true,
    //animCollapse : true,
    height : 250,
    activeTab : 0,
    deferredRender: false, // determining whether or not each tab is rendered only when first accessed (defaults to true).
    autodestroy : false,
    defaults : {bodyStyle : 'padding:10px'},
    items : [tab1,tab2,tab3]
});
```

I want to collapse\expand this only with a button in the window.
The problem is how to eliminate the normal behavior of the collapsible item, because when I click on another tab from default the TabPanel collapses because a collapsible item collapse or expand also if you click on the collapsebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i resolve my problem. If is usefull for anyone this is what i do: 
i give set this properties to my TabPanel:

```
 tabMsgProcessedFill = new Ext.TabPanel({ 
            id:'TabPanel',
            region : 'south',
            plain : true,
            collapsible: true,
            collapsed: true,
            floatable: false,
            split:false,
            maxHeight:250,
            height:250,
            collapseMode:'mini',
            hideLabel: true,
            animCollapse : false,
            activeTab : 0,
            deferredRender: false, // determining whether or not each tab is rendered only when first accessed (defaults to true).
            autodestroy : false,
            defaults : {bodyStyle : 'padding:10px'},
            items : [tab1,tab2,tab3]
            });
```

and make this override

```
Ext.override(Ext.layout.BorderLayout.Region,{ 
getCollapsedEl : function(){
    if(!this.collapsedEl){
        if(!this.toolTemplate){
            var tt = new Ext.Template(
                 '<div class="x-tool x-tool-{id}">*</div>'
            );
            tt.disableFormats = true;
            tt.compile();
            Ext.layout.BorderLayout.Region.prototype.toolTemplate = tt;
        }
        this.collapsedEl = this.targetEl.createChild({
            cls: "x-layout-collapsed x-layout-collapsed-"+this.position,
            id: this.panel.id + '-xcollapsed'
        });
        this.collapsedEl.enableDisplayMode('none'); /*change from block*/

        if(this.collapseMode == 'mini'){
            this.collapsedEl.addClass('x-layout-cmini-'+this.position);
            this.miniCollapsedEl = this.collapsedEl.createChild({
                cls: "x-layout-mini x-layout-mini-"+this.position, html: "*"
            });
            this.miniCollapsedEl.addClassOnOver('x-layout-mini-over');
            this.collapsedEl.addClassOnOver("x-layout-collapsed-over");
            this.collapsedEl.on('click', this.onExpandClick, this, {stopEvent:true});
        }else {
            if((this.collapsible !== false) && !this.hideCollapseTool) {
                var t = this.toolTemplate.append(
                        this.collapsedEl.dom,
                        {id:'expand-'+this.position}, true);
                t.addClassOnOver('x-tool-expand-'+this.position+'-over');
                t.on('click', this.onExpandClick, this, {stopEvent:true});
            }
            if((this.floatable !== false) || this.titleCollapse) {
               this.collapsedEl.addClassOnOver("x-layout-collapsed-over");
               this.collapsedEl.on("click", this[this.floatable ? 'collapseClick' : 'onExpandClick'], this);
            }
        }
    }
    return this.collapsedEl;
}
```

Then the window contain the TabPAnel have layout:'border' and a button who expand or collapse the tabPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach/listen for an event beforeCollapse and return false there which will prevent collapse. Please see **[this link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-beforecollapse)**

Comment: ok, i prove, but another question. I now prove to use the stopevent method, because if i attach a a listener i eliminate the possible to collapse the panel??